# Find to Json line number

Tags: php

I have a Json lines data and would like to convert it into mysql database using php.

I am using

```
$file = file_get_contents($path); $data = json_decode($file, TRUE);
```

to decode the Json file into an array.

This works fine but will return the entire file. I would like to reference to a specific line, for instance decode the json file from line 3 to 6 (should decode from "id:FR08" to "id:"ES01") and ignore the rest of the lines. Please advice how to return the line number in Json lines format, I don't seem to find the code.

Here is a sample of data:

```
{"profile":[    
 {"id":"UK01","num_connections":"270","locality":"UK","industry":"Accounting"}  
,{"id":"ES03","locality":"Spain","experience":[{"start":"2003","organization":[{"name":"org1"}],"end":"Presente","title":"Director"},{"start":" 1995","organization":[{"name":"org2"}],"end":"2003","title":"Manager"}]} 
,{"id":"FR08","num_connections":"10","locality":"France","experience":[{"organization":[{"name":"org1","details":""}],"title":"Manager"}],"industry":"Construction"}   
,{"id":"AD04","num_connections":"68","locality":"Andorra"}   
,{"id":"GE02","locality":"Germany"}  
,{"id":"ES01","num_connections":"450","experience":[{"organization":[{"details":""}],"title":"Directora"}],"industry":"Construction"}  
,{"id":"UK06","num_connections":"1","locality":"Andorra","full_name":"Joana Marisa Sacramento Carvalhais"}     
]}
```

Comment: I don't think you should think about code lines in terms of programming, as they are relative and not absolute (if you open in other editor it might look different etc.). In this case I'd search for the index of "id:FR08" and get that element + three following elements.

Comment: Unless you're getting huge amounts of JSON, then just decode the whole thing and access it like `stdClass`. You risk creating extremely unreadable code going with the first approach.

Comment: I've retagged your question because your actual problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON or MySQL. You have a PHP array and you want to find nth item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter your array.

```
$file = file_get_contents($path); 
$data = json_decode($file, TRUE);
$saving = false;

foreach($data['profile'] as $index => $item)
{
    if($item['id'] == 'FR08')
    {
       $saving = true;
    }

    if($saving === false)
    {
       unset($data['profile'][$index]);
    }

    if($item['id'] == 'ES01')
    {
        $saving = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Estshy, this is a great solution, except that I have a large file with millions of lines and it is not efficient to hard code the 'id'. Is it a way to return the item number instead? Since the file is large my program hangs when decoding the data, so I need to split the data into smaller chunk in a recursive order, for instance from line 1 to 100000, then from 100000 to 200000.

Comment: Yes, it is. Item number is always `$index + 1` inside loop.

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced `if($item['id'] == 'FR08')` with `if($index == $from) ... if($index == $to)` and it is working fine. However my program still hanging, because it has to hold the entire data in an array before splitting them into smaller chunks. Is there any other solution you can think of to handle this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't hanging. Have you been doing something more than filtering array? Have you any error about excedding execution time etc?

Comment: You can insert whole file into MongoDB to work with really large json and then select records by queries. With indexes it's will be really fast.

Comment: I've get 'Out of memory' error as the file size is about 2.5GB and by increasing the memory in php.ini, I've got 'Allowed memory... exhausted'. I've just filtering the array and put each items into a variable and store into database. Never worked with MongoDB, I will research about it.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use an `array_filter` solutions:

```
$file = file_get_contents($path); 
$data = json_decode($file, TRUE);
$flag = array(
    False,
    False,
    True, // line no 3
    True, // line no 4
    True, // line no 5
    True, // line no 6
    False,
    );
function fil($var)
{
    global $flag;
    return $flag[$var];
}

$data = array_filter($data, "fil");
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution may work with smaller file but I have a very large file with millions of lines and need to split it into smaller chunks in order to decode it.